# AutoLayout weird behaviour iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, margins

When I push to a `UIViewControllerB` and then pop back to `UIViewControllerA` entire view of `UIViewControllerA` is about 20 px higher then it should be and in a moment (I guess after `viewDidAppear`) it moves to its normal position. I do not manipulate constrains or `UINavigationBar` settings in any way while this. I do have all elements of `UIViewControllerA` top space to top layout guide. What might cause this? I've worked with storyboard a few and have never faced something like this.

Comment: Well, the status bar is 20px. Does the status bar hide?

Comment: no, nothing is changed, nothing at all

Comment: Can you provide the details of your constraints?

Comment: Transitions between `UIViewControllers` when the top constraint is to the top layout guide sometimes get buggy, the appearing view seems to jump up. I managed to fix mine by adding the top constraint to the `superview` instead of the top layout guide (I however was not using a `UINavigationBar` so it worked for me). I never figured out the reason for the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was somehow caused by removing subview, I've added to cover screen while loading data: after removing this subview, constrains where changed (this only happened on this `UIViewController`, other `UIViewControllers` with this subview are fine). I've fixed it by doing this:

```
self.stopLoading() //removes subview
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent XCode adds some new behaviors. Try setting the constraints of `UIViewControllerA` to have the top one be flush with the bottom of the `UINavigationBar`.